# Windows phone widget

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

Is there any possibility to add widget to my application, not just background image and title, something like e-mail application, facebook application, contact application.
Windows phone ,visual studio 2010, windows 7

Comment: Windows Phone 7 or WP8?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called [Live Tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css), and you can add them to your app. You will find documentation  in [DevCenter](http://dev.windowsphone.com):

[Tiles and notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662933%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css)